# How to align labels and input fields when using CSS and Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've tried everything including similar questions/answers to solve this problem but can't get it to come together.

I'm using Flexbox rows and columns and what I am trying to do is to create four rows of input fields with four items in each (just the final one has two for now) and then to align those such that the labels that go with the input fields align vertically with the row underneath them.
At the moment I can't get them to straighten up so it's very uneven.

So, for example, labels 'Size Meaning:', 'Class;', and 'Unit:' should all be vertically aligned and starting in the same place.

How so I align the labels in the columns vertically?

This is an image of how this looks right now:
[image: input_fields_img]

```css
p { font-size: 24px; }
li { font-size: 24px; }

.page-wrapper {
    margin: 80px;
    align-content: flex-start;
  }

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
  }

  .li-label, .li-input {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .li-label {
    min-width: 80px;
  }
```

```html
<div class='page-wrapper'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column'>
        <form>
            <label for="name"> Name:</label>
            <input type="name" id="name" name="name">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <form>
            <label for="value">Value:</label>
            <input type="value" id="size_value" name="value">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <form>
            <label for="size">Size:</label>
            <input type="size" id="size" name="size">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <form>
            <label for="price">Price:</label>
            <input type="price" id="price_at_size" name="price">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

      <!-------------------END ROW 1----------------------------------------->

      <!-- <div class='page-wrapper'> -->
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='column'>
            <form>
                <label for="currency">Currency:</label>
                <input type="currency" id="currency" name="currency">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <form>
                <label for="year">Year:</label>
                <input type="year" id="series_name" name="year">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <form>
                <label for="class">Class:</label>
                <input type="class" id="class" name="class">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <form>
                <label for="usd">USD:</label>
                <input type="usd" id="usd" name="usd">
            </form>
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->

            <!-------------------END ROW 2----------------------------------------->

        <!-- <div class='page-wrapper'> -->
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="style">Style:</label>
                    <input type="style" id="style" name="style">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="result">Result:</label>
                    <input type="result" id="result" name="result">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="unit">Unit:</label>
                    <input type="unit" id="unit" name="unit">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="Result1">Result1:</label>
                    <input type="Result1" id="Result1" name="Result1">
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>

                <!-------------------END ROW 3----------------------------------------->

        <!-- <div class='text-align:center'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="level">Level:</label>
                    <input type="level" id="level" name="level">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="reference">Reference:</label>
                    <input type="reference" id="reference" name="reference">
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> -->
<!-- 
        <div style="text-align:center"></div>
            <form>
                <label for="sources">Sources:</label>
                <input type="sources" id="sources" name="sources">
                <label for="notes">Notes:</label>
                <input type="notes" id="notes" name="notes">
            </form>
        </div>

                <!-------------------END ROW 4---------------------------------------->
        <br>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
    </div>
```

Comment: So how exactly do you _want_ this to behave then? Do you want to give the labels a min-width that covers the longest label text, or what?

Comment: Btw., unless you had a very specific use case, I rather doubt that wrapping each input into its _own_ form element, makes much sense.

Comment: Since you’re trying to align things in two dimensions rather than one, css grid is a better bet than flex.

Comment: Yes you are right @CBroe, that was a result of copy and paste from the first inputs. You can disregard those!

Comment: @CBroe I was hoping to get every label to start at the same spot upon creation of a column. Isn't there a way to align items per column like that?

Comment: There _are_ no real "columns" here, you just have a couple of flex items, that are allowed to break into multiple "rows". But that does not mean that the individual items have _any_ kind of "connection" between them. So unless you _specify_ a width for these items, they will all take as much space as they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lot of work need to be done in HTML part.

But i have just ignored it and added missing closing div in snippet.

you can change the values of width as per your need for form elements.

```css
p { font-size: 24px; }
li { font-size: 24px; }

.page-wrapper {
    /*margin: 80px;*/
    align-content: flex-start;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
width: 740px;
  }

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
  }

  .li-label, .li-input {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .li-label {
    min-width: 80px;
  }
  
.column form { display: flex; }
.column form label{ min-width: 70px; }
.column form input{ max-width: 98px; }
```

```html
<div class='page-wrapper'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column'>
        <form>
            <label for="name"> Name:</label>
            <input type="name" id="name" name="name">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <form>
            <label for="value">Value:</label>
            <input type="value" id="size_value" name="value">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <form>
            <label for="size">Size:</label>
            <input type="size" id="size" name="size">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <form>
            <label for="price">Price:</label>
            <input type="price" id="price_at_size" name="price">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

      <!-------------------END ROW 1----------------------------------------->

      <!-- <div class='page-wrapper'> -->
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='column'>
            <form>
                <label for="currency">Currency:</label>
                <input type="currency" id="currency" name="currency">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <form>
                <label for="year">Year:</label>
                <input type="year" id="series_name" name="year">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <form>
                <label for="class">Class:</label>
                <input type="class" id="class" name="class">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <form>
                <label for="usd">USD:</label>
                <input type="usd" id="usd" name="usd">
            </form>
          </div>
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->

            <!-------------------END ROW 2----------------------------------------->

        <!-- <div class='page-wrapper'> -->
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="style">Style:</label>
                    <input type="style" id="style" name="style">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="result">Result:</label>
                    <input type="result" id="result" name="result">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="unit">Unit:</label>
                    <input type="unit" id="unit" name="unit">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="Result1">Result1:</label>
                    <input type="Result1" id="Result1" name="Result1">
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>

                <!-------------------END ROW 3----------------------------------------->
<!--
        <div class='text-align:center'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="level">Level:</label>
                    <input type="level" id="level" name="level">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class='column'>
                <form>
                    <label for="reference">Reference:</label>
                    <input type="reference" id="reference" name="reference">
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> -->
<!-- 
        <div style="text-align:center"></div>
            <form>
                <label for="sources">Sources:</label>
                <input type="sources" id="sources" name="sources">
                <label for="notes">Notes:</label>
                <input type="notes" id="notes" name="notes">
            </form>
        </div>

                <!-------------------END ROW 4---------------------------------------->
        <br>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
    </div>
```

Comment: Off the top of your head, can you suggest a way to improve the HTML (apart from fixing the form copy and paste thing I did)?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't what you want placing each element to it's own column class like this? Also you need to wrap all the elements in only one form:

```
<div class='page-wrapper'>
  <form>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column'>
        <label for="name"> Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <input type="name" id="name" name="name">
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <label for="value">Value:</label>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <input type="value" id="size_value" name="value">
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <label for="size">Size:</label>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <input type="size" id="size" name="size">
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <label for="price">Price:</label>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <input type="price" id="price_at_size" name="price">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-------------------END ROW 1----------------------------------------->
    <!-- <div class='page-wrapper'> -->
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column'>
        <label for="currency">Currency:</label>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <input type="currency" id="currency" name="currency">
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <label for="year">Year:</label>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <input type="year" id="series_name" name="year">
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <label for="class">Class:</label>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <input type="class" id="class" name="class">
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <label for="usd">USD:</label>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <input type="usd" id="usd" name="usd">
      </div>
      <!-- </div> -->
      <!-------------------END ROW 2----------------------------------------->
      <!-- <div class='page-wrapper'> -->
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='column'>
          <label for="style">Style:</label>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <input type="style" id="style" name="style">
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <label for="result">Result:</label>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <input type="result" id="result" name="result">
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <label for="unit">Unit:</label>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <input type="unit" id="unit" name="unit">
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <label for="Result1">Result1:</label>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <input type="Result1" id="Result1" name="Result1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-------------------END ROW 3----------------------------------------->
      <!-- <div class='text-align:center'><div class='row'><div class='column'><label for="level">Level:</label></div><div class='column'><input type="level" id="level" name="level"></div><div class='column'><label for="reference">Reference:</label></div><div class='column'><input type="reference" id="reference" name="reference"></div></div></div> -->
      <!-- 
        <div style="text-align:center"></div><label for="sources">Sources:</label></div><div class='column'><input type="sources" id="sources" name="sources"></div><div class='column'><label for="notes">Notes:</label></div><div class='column'><input type="notes" id="notes" name="notes"></div>
                                                            <!-------------------END ROW 4---------------------------------------->
      <br>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```